# Dynamic Form Generation - Field depending on 2 Others

Tags: php, forms, events, symfony, field

.Hello Everyone,

I am having a hard time trying to generate a field that depends on 2 others dynamically. I tried different things but I got to a point were I just don't know what to do anymore.

Basically I have an entity ***Reservation*** which contains (among others) 1 field ***showw*** pointing to the entity ***Showw***.
The entity ***Showw*** has 2 fields ***theatre*** and ***play*** pointing to 2 other entities of the same name.

What I want now is to build the ***Reservation Form*** so that I can first select the ***theatre*** and ***play*** and then select a ***showw*** with the same ***theatre*** and ***play***.

So I need to filter the ***showw*** field. Here is what I did :
The event occurring at the initialization works fine (the field ***showw*** is correctly filtered) but not the event occuring at the submit (***showw*** is always empty).

```
<?php
// src/MySite/MyBundle/Form/ReservationType.php

namespace MySite\MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

use MySite\MyBundle\Entity\ShowwRepository;

class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    // Generating Form
    $builder
        ->add('play',           'entity',   array('label'  => 'Play',
                                                'class' => 'MySiteMyBundle:Play',
                                                'property'  => 'title',
                                                'required' => false))
        ->add('theatre',        'entity',   array('label'  => 'Theatre',
                                                'class' => 'MySiteMyBundle:Theatre',
                                                'property'  => 'name',
                                                'required' => false))
    ;

    // Modifier to Generate the Showw Field
    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $play, $theatre) {
        $form->add('showw',     'entity',   array('label'  => 'Show',
                                                'class' => 'MySiteMyBundle:Showw',
                                                'property'  => 'showwDateAsString',
                                                'query_builder' => function(ShowwRepository $r) use ($play, $theatre) { return $r->wherePlayAndTheatre($play, $theatre); }));
    };

    // Initialisation Event
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getPlay(), $data->getTheatre());
        }
    );

    // Submit Event
    $builder->get('play')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            $theatre = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()->getTheatre();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData(), $theatre);
        }
    );
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MySite\MyBundle\Entity\Reservation'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'MySite_MyBundle_reservationtype';
}
}
```

Now I have several questions:

1. I made some tests and the problem is that, in the ***submit*** event, I can't manage to get the ***theatre*** value (variable ***$theatre*** in the code) which is always NULL.
   What is the correct code to get the value of the field ***theatre*** when triggering the submit event on the ***play*** field?
2. In fact I would like to trigger the submit event on the form as it is done at the initialization because otherwise I'll have to write the same event for ***theatre***.
   I tried to copy the code of the initialization just changing the event to ***POST_SUBMIT*** but then I get an error message saying that I can't add a field to the form at the submit.
   Apparently Symfony  does a match between the form and the add when I trigger the event from the field but not the form.
   Why? What is different?
3. Bonus question : How can I insert the field in the middle of the form (for example between ***play*** and ***theatre***)?

Thank you for your help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be better of using two forms.

the first form asks for the theater and play and you will use javascript to tell if both fields have been filled out and then ajax a request to get the second form which you render in an empty div you already have laid out for it.